# Issue with pants build tool on a "Hello World" example

Tags: python, deployment, build, build-process, pants

I was doing a "Hello World" exercise with Twitter's Pants build tool. After cloned the "pants" repo - source, I successfully configured pants on my local.

First, I created an nested dir in the repo as:

```
$ mkdir -p mark/python/project_test
```

Then, I created two files in that dir to specify my app and BUILD as:

```
$ touch mark/python/project_test/Hello_world.py
$ touch mark/python/project_test/BUILD
```

Hello_World.py:

```
print "Hello World!"
```

BUILD:

```
python_binary(name="myapp",
          source="Hello_world.py"
         )
```

It ran perfectly when i run it with ./pants like:

```
$ ./pants run mark/python/project_test:myapp
$ Hello World!
```

Then, I was trying to add dependencies by change the "Hello_world.py" as:

```
import utility
print "Hello World!", utility.user(), "!"
```

I also created the utility.py in the same dir as:

```
import os 

def user():
return os.environ['USER']
```

As I add dependencies to my original app, I also modified the BUILD as:

```
python_library(name="app-lib",
          source=globs("*py")
          )
python_binary(name="myapp",
          source="hello_world.py",
          dependencies=[pants(':app-lib')]
         )
```

However, when I called the ./pants with the same command, it returned error:

```
$ ./pants run mark/python/project_test:myapp
Exception caught: (<class 'pants.base.cmd_line_spec_parser.BadSpecError'>)

Exception message: name 'pants' is not defined
while executing BUILD file BuildFile(mark/python/project_test/BUILD,       
FileSystemProjectTree(/Users/mli/workspace/source))
Loading addresses from 'mark/python/project_test' failed.
when translating spec mark/python/project_test:myapp
```

There are currently three files on my dir:

```
$ ls mark/python/project_test
$ BUILD Hello_world.py utility.py
```

Why my app can't load the library from utility.py and what is the right way to arrange folder tree and BUILD files?

- I am sort of new to build tool and would really appreciate if somebody could provide a bit context of using pants when answering the question. Thanks!!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make your project run with a few small adjustments. Your issues were:

1. There used to be a `pants()` wrapper for pants shortcuts but it doesn't exist anymore. I think you have the syntax slightly wrong even if it did.
2. You used `source` and `sources` interchangeably when they are in fact distinct.

For number 2, it is perhaps a subtle distinction:

- `python_binary` has one `source` - the entrypoint for the created binary.
- `python_library` has `sources` - an arbitrary number of files to be imported into other projects.

If you change your `BUILD` file to match the definition below, you should have success rerunning your invocation. Good luck!

```
  python_library(
    name='app-lib',
    sources=globs('*.py'),
  )

  python_binary(
    name="myapp",
    source="hello_world.py",
    dependencies=[':app-lib']
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mateor ! I see. I might be using an old BUILD syntax when there is updated version. It works perfectly! Again, thank you!